# How can I access URL of an ActiveStorage attachment at S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I migrated form paperclip to ActiveStorage and I'm struggling a litte with URLs. I was using `service_url`, but wasn't working for me because everytime you call that function, it returns a different URL.

Im trying to use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path`. Locally, it works. I just have to acess `http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/disk/<etc>`, where `rails/active_storage/disk/<etc>` was given to me from the method call.

But how can I access this from my Amazon S3? I enabled static website hosting, but if I hit `http://my-production-bucket.s3-website.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/<etc>`, I get an error. Im I hitting the wrong endpoint/wrong host? What else should I do to get an unique (not dynamic) URL, is there another easiest way?

My storage.yml:

```
amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['AWS_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET'] %>
  region: 'sa-east-1'
  bucket: 'production-bucket'

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

production.rb:

```
config.active_storage.service = :amazon
```

Comment: What error are you getting? There's every chance your URL is correct and you've not setup access permissions for public properly

Comment: I don't actually know. When setting Static Website hosting, we need to set index and error pages. When I try to access `http://my-production-bucket.s3-website.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/rails/active_storage/blobs/<etc>`, I get the error page.
Any way, I could not find that path browsing at S3. Does this make sense? Or it should have folders like `rails` and `active_storage`? I tried creating them just to make sure they were public, but still did not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs for service_url https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.0/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-service_url

> Returns the URL of the variant on the service. This URL is intended to be short-lived for security and not used directly with users. Instead, the service_url should only be exposed as a redirect from a stable, possibly authenticated URL. Hiding the service_url behind a redirect also gives you the power to change services without updating all URLs. And it allows permanent URLs that redirect to the service_url to be cached in the view.
>
> Use url_for(variant) (or the implied form, like +link_to variant+ or +redirect_to variant+) to get the stable URL for a variant that points to the ActiveStorage::VariantsController, which in turn will use this service_call method for its redirection.

It recommends you to implement some kind of proxy action on your app. You give the fixed url for that action and then redirect the request to the current service_url.

Comment: I was using `service_url`, and start using `rails_blob_path` because I did not want URL updating everytime I call the method. Is there some way using `service_url` or `url_for` and do not keep changing generated URL?

Comment: @KilmerLuizAleluia, the solution is explained with that quote from the docs. You have to define you custom fixed urls pointing to an action that redirects the request to the actual service_url each time. You can try with `url_for(variant)` as the second paragraph suggest since it looks like VariantsController already handles that redirection.